# Cable Internet on Motorola Surfboard SVG6582 and dynamic IP on TL-R600VPN

Tags: networking, router, cable-modem, dynamic-ip

I have the following devices at home:
Motorola Surfboard SVG6582 and TL-R600VPN.

My internet comes from a cable connection(DHCP) on Motorola device.
I have two ethernet adapters on my box and I did these settings:

One ethernet cable is connected at Motorola device to the TL-R600PVN LAN port.
Another ethernet cable is connected at the TL-R600VPN going to my ethernet adapter.

I disabled DHCP on R600VPN and I didn't use WAN port.
The problem is that I would like to setup a Dynamic IP from NO-IP account into the TL-R600PVN device but I can't reach the internet.

Tried to configure on Motorola device but doesn't have support for No-IP settings and I would like to configure NO-IP account on the TL-R600VPN.

Comment: You need to set the cable modem to bridge, and let the router route. The setting you need for the router are going to work on a public IP address assigned to the WAN port of the router.

Comment: Bridges don't NAT because they are ignorant of layer-3 protocols, including IP.

Comment: @RonMaupin Need I do disable NAPT mode, DHCP and Wireless to do that?
I don't want to buy another Wireless router. TL-R600VPN is just a VPN router.

Comment: If you want to us what you have described then you will need to set the modem to bridge, disabling routing. Then, you would need to get an AP for Wi-Fi, and connect it to your router. You can only do what you want to do on the device with the public IP address. The device needs to know when it has changed, and what it is to tell the service about that. You router behind a NAT on the modem cannot do that.